# Filtered data doesn't show in my UITableView Objective C iOS7

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to bind "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" in my UITableView. Filtered array has the right data but it doesn't display in tableview. When I enter something in search bar it displays blank table view.
In function "cellForRowAtIndexPath" when it binds the correct data but still doesn't show up. In the same function I also changed the code from
**UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];**
to 
**UITableViewCell *cell = [self.personTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];**

then it throws the following exception:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Person length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1780ca170'

Code:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    return [self.filteredPersonArray count];
 } else {
    return [self.personArray count];
}
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Person *person;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
    person = (Person *)[self.filteredPersonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
     person = (Person *)[self.personArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", person.firstName, person.lastName];
// so on;
return cell;
}

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
// Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
// Remove all objects from the filtered search array
[self.filteredPersonArray removeAllObjects];
// Filter the array using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *lastNamepredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.lastName contains[c] %@",searchText];
//NSPredicate *firstNamePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.firstName contains[c] %@",scope];
//tempArray = [tempArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:lastNamepredicate];
self.filteredPersonArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.personArray  
filteredArrayUsingPredicate:lastNamepredicate]];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
// Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:  
[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller 
shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
// Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
[self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
 [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
// Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this problem:
I referred to different tableview objects while creating the cell in case of 
1. Loading the data after search
2. Loading the data in tableview

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    Person *person;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) 
    {
        cell = [self.personTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell"];
        person = (Person *)[self.filteredPersonArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    } else {
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PersonCell"];
        person = (Person *)[self.personArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    nameLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", person.firstName,     person.lastName];
    // so on;
    return cell;
}
```